# linq order by 2 parameters

Tags: .net, linq

I need to order a list with linq based on 2 parameters a Boolean and a DateTime

The top of the list has to be the Booleans that are true and then ordered by DateTime

At the bottom of the list we need the Booleans that are false, also order by DateTime

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://www.codeducky.org/linq-operators-and-ordering/ is a nice post abot ordering in LINQ.  Take a look at the "OrderBy" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the boolean, you want a descending order (`false` compares like it's smaller than `true`). To add additional ordering parameters, you use `ThenBy` (for dates: oldest on top)/`ThenByDescending` (for dates: newest on top). I think the methods you're looking for are [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855.aspx) and [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534743.aspx).

```
myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.MyBool).ThenBy(x => x.MyDateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`Enumerable.ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the second parameter, For Ordering in descending order use [`Enumerable.OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [`Enumerable.ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534736%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For your particular case, you need `true` to appear first and then you want to get the records sorted by date. If you want to get latest date first, then you will need descending order. In that case your query would be:

```
var query = list.OrderByDescending(r => r.BoolProperty)
                .ThenByDescending(r => r.DateTimeProperty);
```

Considering you have `List<DummyClass>` like:

```
List<DummyClass> list = new List<DummyClass>
{
  new DummyClass() { BoolProperty = true, DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)},
  new DummyClass() { BoolProperty = true, DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)},
  new DummyClass() { BoolProperty = false, DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)},
  new DummyClass() { BoolProperty = false, DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)},

};
```

Where `DummyClass` is defined as:

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

For output you can use:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bool {0}, DateTime {1}" , item.BoolProperty, item.DateTimeProperty);
}
```

Output would be:

```
Bool True, DateTime 09/05/2014 1:18:53 PM
Bool True, DateTime 08/05/2014 1:18:53 PM
Bool False, DateTime 10/05/2014 1:18:53 PM
Bool False, DateTime 06/05/2014 1:18:53 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
var result = yourList
             .OrderBy(r=> r.BooleanField)
             .ThenByDescending(r=> r.DateTimeField);
```

You have to do `DateTime` descending to get the latest one first.

For `Boolean` if you want sorted on `true` first then use `OrderByDescending` on it as well:

```
var result = yourList
                 .OrderByDescending(r=> r.BooleanField)
                 .ThenByDescending(r=> r.DateTimeField);
```